# Visual Studio 2010, Visual Basic 10, debugger not running

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I have Visual Basic 10 program written in Visual Studio 10.  For most of my development I would hit the play button and it would build and run.  Suddenly, with no major changes to the program, it stopped running.  I can hit the play button and it builds, but it doesn't run, and it doesn't show any error messages.  I can run the .exe file and it works fine, and I can also use `CTRL + F5` and it works.  How can I "fix" the debugger?

Summary:

VB10 in VS2010
can code fine
hit play button (`F5`) and builds with no errors
.exe file works (`CTRL + F5` also works)
using play button, program never starts

Thanks for the answers!

Comment: Do you get anything in the "output" window?

Comment: In configuration manager, are all the relevant projects selected to build? Are you building in the correct mode? (Release / Debug)

Comment: I didn't get anything in the output window and the configuration manager is set to debug